# Inherited some bad Java generics

Tags: java, generics

This is a nasty problem, and it might be that the design is just bad.

Writing a set of simple charts components (pie, bar & line charts) and am choking on some generics stuff. In advance, I'm sure there are many Java APIs for doing exactly what I'm trying to do here (charting/reports/etc.), however I'm interested in this as a general generics problem; the fact that it involves charts & reporting components is trivial.

Every chart inherits from a generic abstract base class `Chart`:

```
public abstract class Chart<T extends ChartComponent>
{
    private List<T> components;

    // ...rest of the Chart class
}
```

The reason why we have `T extends ChartComponent` is because every chart subclass will be comprised of 1+ so-called *chart components* (bars, lines, pie wedges, etc.):

```
public abstract class ChartComponent
{
    private Color color;

    // .. rest of ChartComponent class
}

public class PieWedge extends ChartComponent
{
    double wedgeValue;

    // ... rest of PieWedge class
}
```

Putting this design together:

```
public class PieChart extends Chart<PieWedge>
{
    // ... thus its list of ChartComponents is actually a List<PieWedge>
}
```

This way, `PieChart` isn't generic (nor should it be) and is always of type `Chart<PieWedge>`.

I previously had the same setup for bar and line charts, which were defined as `BarChart extends Chart<BarGroup>` and `LineChart extends Chart<Line>` respectively (since a bar chart consists of 1+ groups of bars, and a line chart consists of 1+ lines).

Now I want to abstract Bar and Line charts out even further. Both of these charts are actually plotted against an (x,y) Cartesian graph with x- and y-axes; this is as opposed to a pie chart which is not plotted against any such axes.

Ideally, I wanted to create a new abstract class called `CartesianChart` which extended `Chart`, and then have `BarChart` and `LineChart` both extend `CartesianChart`. This new `CartesianChart` would introduce new properties (`xAxisLabel`, `gridTurnedOn`, etc.) that logically apply to bar/line charts but not pie charts.

Furthermore, to restrict `CartesianChart` so that it could only have `chartComponents` of type `BarGroup` or `Line` (and not `PieWedge`), I would like to create a new chart component type like `CartesianComponent extends ChartComponent`, and then have `BarGroup`/`Line` extend that. Doing so would prevent code like this from compiling:

```
LineChart lineChart = new LineChart();
lineChart.addLine(new PieWedge());
```

Since `Line` extends `CartesianComponent`, but `PieWedge` only extends `ChartComponent`. Thus, before getting to my problem we have the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
Chart
    CartesianChart
        BarChart
        LineChart
    PieChart

ChartComponent
    CartesianComponent
        BarGroup
        Line
    PieWedge

PieChart extends Chart<PieWedge>

CartesianChart extends Chart<CartesianComponent>

BarGroup extends CartesianComponent
Line extends CartesianComponent

BarChart extends CartesianChart<BarGroup>
LineChart extends CartesianChart<Line>
```

The problem with this setup is that on both `BarChart` and `LineChart` it gives a compiler error complaining that `CartesianChart` is not generic. **This makes complete sense, but I'm not sure what I can do to fix it!**

If I try to re-define `CartesianChart`:

```
public abstract class CartesianChart<T extends CartesianComponent> extends Chart<CartesianComponent>
{
    // ...
}
```

I get "type mismatch" compiler errors all through my bar/line chart code. In every instance of the error, it states that it is expecting arguments of type `List<CartesianComponent>` but instead found `List<BarGroup>` or `List<Line>` and that they are not suitable substitutes.

Hopefully, this is a quick fix somewhere in the class definition of `CartesianChart` and/or `CartesianComponent`. Otherwise I may have to re-design the entire chart library. Either way, I'm interested in any and all suggestions, **except** ones like "*Hey, why don't you just try JFreeCharts or* ...". Again, I'm interested in the solution here as it related to solving a broad range of similar generics problems; the fact that this involves reporting/charting is trivial.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by making `Chart` generic?  In other words, why not just define `class Chart { private List<ChartComponent> components; }`?

Comment: `public abstract class CartesianChart<T extends CartesianComponent> extends Chart<T>`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions here. I will try both of your suggestions here. Please see my comment below @nicholas.hauschild's answer about my fear that extending Chart<T> would not prevent subclasses making Chart's where T does not extend ChartComponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Chart` class contains the `List<T>` that you speak of, so when you you define your `CartesianChart` abstract class to extend `Chart<CartesianComponent>`, you are saying that `List<T>` is really `List<CartesianComponent>`.

Really, what you want is to just use the generic as you defined it in your abstract class (that is, `<T extends CartesianComponent>`).  I would try doing this and see how it works out.

```
public abstract class CartesianChart<T extends CartesianComponent> extends Chart<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That is a very good suggestion (and thank you!), however I am worried that this would allow subclasses to be defined like so: public class Diagram extends Chart<Widget>, where Widget is not a ChartComponent subclass. It is important that all type "T"'s inherit (at some point) from ChartComponent.

Comment: It wouldn't actually, because you have already defined `T` in this scope to be restricted to `CartesianComponent`'s (per `CartesianChart<T extends CartesianComponent>`).  Try my suggestion and then try adding a `Widget` to it...

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces.

```
public interface IsAPieChart {

}

public interface IsACartesianChart {

}
```

They don't even need any methods.

Your method profile for addLine() would read:

```
public void addLine(IsACartesianChart cartesianChart);
```

Your abstract classes would read:

```
public class PieChart extends Chart<PieWedge> implements IsAPieChart
{
    // ... thus its list of ChartComponents is actually a List<PieWedge>
}
```

And use IsACartesianChart to mark CartesianChart in the same way.  Now addLine() won't accept anything of PieChart because no PieChart implements the IsACartesianChart interface, but it will take anything of a subclass of CartesianChart because all the subclasses implement IsACartesianChart.

Using interfaces like this is a great way to reintroduce distinctions that have been lost when a bunch of classes trace back to the same superclass.  Superclasses and subclasses form a strict hierarchy, while interfaces can be attached wherever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason why we have `T extends ChartComponent` is because every chart
>   subclass will be comprised of 1+ so-called chart components (bars,
>   lines, pie wedges, etc.):

This is your red-herring, there is no need to use a Generic here. This is a `Composition` problem, not a `Generics` problem.

Just make your list look like:

```
private List<ChartComponent> components;
```

This is all the type safety you should need.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this suggestion later this week when I have a chance.